# 2 statements creating objects with regular new expression, any difference?

Tags: c++, creation

Consider the following class with a user-defined default ctor.

```
class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass()
    :data_(999) {
    }
    double getData() const {
        return data_;
    }

private:
    double data_;
};
```

Then we create objects:

```
TestClass *p2 = new TestClass();
TestClass *p1 = new TestClass;
```

Any difference for using the 2 statements above in any condition?

Thank you,

Comment: Both statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No difference.

Longer answer: §5.3.4,15 states that

> A *new-expression* that creates an object of type `T` initializes that object as follows:
>   — If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is **default-initialized** (§8.5); if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.
>   — Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of §8.5 for direct-initialization.

And §8.5,16 says

> If the initializer is (), the object is **value-initialized**.

Now what is value-initialization and default-initialization, is defined by §8.5,5-7:

> To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type T means:
>   — **if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), [...]**
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, the object’s first non-static named data member is zeroinitialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
>   — if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.
>
> To *default-initialize* an object of type T means:
>   — **if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called [...]**
>   — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>   — **otherwise, no initialization is performed.**
>   [...]
>
> To *value-initialize* an object of type T means:
>   — **if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called [...]**
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   — **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**

(emphasis mine)

Together, since your class has a user provided default constructor, value initialization and default initialization is the same, so both new expressions give the same behavior, namely the default constructor is called.

It is a different thing with e.g. ints:

```
int *p2 = new int(); // value-initialized, i.e. zero-initialized, *p2 is 0
int *p1 = new int;   // default-initialized, i.e. no initialization. *p1 is some garbage. Or whatever.
```

Comment: Sorry I tried to separate paragraphs. But seems it's not allowed in comments.

Comment: Thx @Arne! So adding "()" only affects initialization part, not allocation part, even when the OS is out of memory etc., right?</br>

To _default-initialize_ an object of type T means:
— if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the **default constructor** for T is called.</br>

If user doesn't supply a **default constructor**, C++ generates one for you which doesn't init primitive and compound types; while in _value-initialize_, **the object is zero-initialized**. This is the diff when we don't define a default constructor for **TestClass**, right?</br>

Comment: Almost right, It will be zero-initialized **or the default-ctor will be called (if non-trivial)** Meaning, even if the constructor is not user-defined, it will be called if it is nontrivial.